# Scrapy Python Craigslist Scraper

Tags: python, scrapy, scraper, craigslist

I am trying to scrape Craigslist classifieds using **Scrapy** to extract items that are for sale.

I am able to extract **date, post title, and post url** but am having trouble extracting **price**.

For some reason the current code extracts **all** of the prices, but when I remove the **//** before the price span look up the price field returns as empty.

Can someone please review the code below and help me out?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

    class MySpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "craig"
        allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = ["http://longisland.craigslist.org/search/sss?sort=date&query=raptor%20660&srchType=T"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//p")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item['date'] = titles.select('span[@class="itemdate"]/text()').extract()
        item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        item ['price'] = titles.select('//span[@class="itempp"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Hi there, I am building a similar script and I see people use craigslist_sample.items but I'm not sure how to get that package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itempp` appears to be inside of another element, `itempnr`. Perhaps it would work if you were to change `//span[@class="itempp"]/text()` to `span[@class="itempnr"]/span[@class="itempp"]/text()`.

Comment: Does it still give nothing?

Comment: It was only giving nothing on the nearby results on the bottom half of the page.

Comment: For some reason my date field has quotes in it which throws off my csv file a bit.. any thoughts on how I can only extract what is within the quotes?

Comment: I would switch `'` and `"`, so the python strings are surrounded with `"` and the scrapy strings are surrounded with `'`.

Comment: I didn't even notice that was different.. thank you for pointing it out..Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.. It looks like Craigslist just formats the dates that way.

This is how it currently extracts

 {'date': [u'\n\t\t\t\t Mar  8\n            \t', u'\n\t\t\t'],
  'link': [u'http://longisland.craigslist.org/mcy/3666669932.html'],
  'price': [u' $3000'],
  'title': [u'YAMAHA RAPTOR 660-2002...TRIPLE BLACK...TASTEFULLY MODIFIED...FAST !!!']}