# Recursive Scraping Craigslist with Scrapy and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm having trouble getting the spider to follow the next page of ads without following every link it finds, eventually returning every craigslist page. I've played around with the rule as I know that's where the problem lies, but I either get just the first page, every page on craigslist, or nothing. Any help?

Here's my current code:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

class PageSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "cto"
    allowed_domains = ["medford.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://medford.craigslist.org/cto/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=("medford.craigslist.org", )),
        callback='parse_page', follow=True
        ),

    )

        def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//div[@class="content"]/p[@class="row"]')

        for row in rows:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            link = row.xpath('.//span[@class="pl"]/a')
            item['title'] = link.xpath("text()").extract()
            item['link'] = link.xpath("@href").extract()
            item['price'] = row.xpath('.//span[@class="l2"]/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()

            url = 'http://medford.craigslist.org{}'.format(''.join(item['link']))
            yield Request(url=url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_item_page)


    def parse_item_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = response.meta['item']
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//section[@id="postingbody"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an `allow` argument of [SgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=sgmllinkextractor#sgmllinkextractor):

> **allow** (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular
>   expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls
>   must match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will
>   match all links.

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='http://medford.craigslist.org/cto/'), 
         callback='parse_page', follow=True),
)
```

This will keep all links under `http://medford.craigslist.org/cto/` url.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again! I had basically tried variations of that, just didn't get the right combination. Debugging is fun :)